# Time series modeling the number of users of a mobile app

Tags: time-series, estimation, modeling

I want to model the number of users of an mobile app. This app has two kinds of users: *free* and *paid*. I thought of this autoregressive model:

$x_t = Ax_{t-1}$

with $x_t$ being a 4-dimensional vector, with quantities (all in period $t$) for the numbers of

- mobile users
- visitors of the app page
- free users
- paid users

I imagined $A$ as follows:

$A = \begin{bmatrix}
a & 0 & b & c \\
d & e & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1-e & f & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1-(b+f) & g
\end{bmatrix}$

Each parameter is the proportion of people in a group going to another group. Example: $f$ is the proportion of *free users* that remain *free users* in the next period; $d$ is the number of mobile users that visited the app page, and so on.

Problems I see with this model:

1. $b$ and $c$ are the proportion of users that leave the app. Not sure if it's nice to put them in the group of *mobile users*, or make another dimension for the group *former users*, that don't register back in the app.
2. The number of mobile users grow in time, so the way I thought to cope with this is by not demanding that $a$ and $d$ sum is 1. Not sure if it's valid.

So, the question is: how can I make a better model that I could feed the numbers after the launch of the app and get good estimates for these parameters, and good estimates for future numbers of users?

Comment: Would be great to share experiences if we ever come to cope with our similar problems. Write to roland dot kofler at gmail if you want to share

Comment: Did you ever receive any feedback on this or everyone left you dead in the water?

Comment: Dead in the water for four years,  @TedTaylorofLife :)