# How to fit a distribution if the samples have not been draw randomly

Tags: distributions, curve-fitting, rare-events

I read the posts [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/140496/how-to-draw-a-random-sample-from-a-generalized-beta-distribution-of-the-second-k) and [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/88836/how-good-is-monte-carlo-simulation-when-the-variable-distribution-is-unknown).

The real-life problem is: In a rare event simulation catastrophic events occur extremely seldom. The performance of my underlying system has an unknown distribution and gets poor only in these rare events.

I want to estimate the distribution of my system performance using a rare event simulation.

To explain things see the following two curves.

[image: Distribution of samples and criticality]

The blue line shows the distribution of scenarios. There are very common scenarios and there are rare scenarios and if I run my simulation I get scenarios according to this blue distribution.
The orange curve describes the performance of my system. Only in the rare events the criticality rises and leads to catastrophic outcomes.

I would consider myself beginner/intermediate when it comes to applied statistics.
What I want to to: I want to fit samples from a long-tail distribution but the samples have been modified by an unknown second distribution.

In my simulation I draw samples from the blue distribution and calculate the outcome of my system using the CDF of the orange curve.

[image: Samples from the original distribution]

[image: Observations of the system according to both distributions]

As expected the sample distribution is an extremely screwed version of the original blue distribution.
My task is to derive the original orange distribution from the sample distribution.

I know that if I apply a log() to my samples the results resembles the original orange curve quite well but completely destroys my mean and variance.
This is where I am stuck atm. Can you please help? To simplify things a little I give you the actual distributions. In real-life these are unknown and have to be assumed or regressed.

[image]

Question: How can I derive the parameters of the orange curve only by using the samples and some model assumptions regarding the original distributions.